# Change window.screen.width/height in webdriver.Firefox by python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, screen-resolution

For test i need change a screen resolution of browser (window.screen.*). I testing a javascript what working with browser depending on window.screen.width/height values. Can't find a solution. 
In side of html-page it's can do next code:

```
window.screen.__defineGetter__('width', function(){return 800;});
window.screen.__defineGetter__('height', function(){return 600;});
```

But i need load page already with need values of window.screen.width/height.
How can i do this with webdriver.Firefox?

**UPD:** browser.set_window_size(..., ...) no right solution. After that javascript alert(window.screen.size) show my realy resolution, not from set_window_size(..., ...). set_window_size(..., ...) change only size of browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the resolution of the screen using Selenium. You can simulate it with window size by using the `set_window_size` method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(800, 600)
```

Comment: Yes, but it not solution. alert(window.screen.width) show my right screen resolution, not 800*600.